# Exactly what does reputation unlock/buy (KSP)?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm selling off all my reputation and I'm noticing the game is a little harder than usual.

[image: Reputation]

I've never been told what reputation does. What exactly does reputation do/give/unlock?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## What is it?

***Reputation is one of the three currencies for KSP, the other two being Funds and Science.***


Reputation is a measure to determine the player's success rate at contracts. It can be gained by completing them and getting Kerbals safely back to Kerbin. Failing a contract or losing Kerbals reduces the reputation.

---

## What does it do?

Reputation regulates the amounts of each level of contracts on offer, as well as changing the prestige of available contracts. It does nothing else ATM

---

## Sources

[KSP Wiki: 0.24 Update](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/0.24)
[KSP Wiki: Reputation](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Reputation)